# Getting error when clicking on Licence Details - on a PaaS setup

Tags: azure

Getting Exception when i clicked on Licence details..

Currently my Application is host on Azure Pass using sitecore version 8.2 update 3

[image]

> Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Message: Unable to find the specified file.
>   Source: mscorlib
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
>
> at Sitecore.Configuration.AboutFormRenderer.GetCustomAttribute[T](Assembly assembly)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.AboutFormRenderer.GetModuleInfo(String moduleName)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.AboutFormRenderer.GetModulesInfo(IEnumerable`1 moduleNames)
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.AboutFormRenderer.RenderModules()
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.AboutFormRenderer.RenderForm()
>      at Sitecore.Configuration.About.ToHtml()
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.About.AboutForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Sitecore is trying to access the license file as if it was on the local filesystem - this will not work in a PaaS setting.

Comment: In the log, it's trying to get the module name.. is it something related with module name? I check the dll code but didn't find the exact issue, seems like some configurations are missing

Comment: Do you have custom DLLs deployed? Have you validated that the Sitecore binaries are the correct files?

Comment: I got the solution, Xunite.Core DLL was missing in the environment

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the error on my instance.

Please check that all the custom code is deployed with your solution.

If you still have an issue please open a case with Microsoft.

Comment: I got the solution, Xunite.Core DLL was missing in the Pass environment